# Handling rendering before async completes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Having an async action creator in `componentWillMount` takes time to complete,

In the meanwhile, component is rendered once or twice without the data provided until reducer changes the state and contain it,

Please clarify what is the best way to handle the initial component render(s) that has no data yet,

I find myself doing things like:

```
render() {
   if (!this.props.item) return <div></div>
   // this fails during initial renders without the if condition above.
   const { item: { foo: { bar } } } = this.props
}
```

I know I can have default state in `mapStateToProps` but this won't work when entities (such as item.foo.bar) have nested fields.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use mapStateToProps to map item of state(redux) with item in props. Such as, when async task done then the item in props will automatically change. 
When props changed, component will render againt.

In render function, you can implement:

```
render(){
  {
    !this.props.item ? <div>No data</div> 
    : <div>
        item.foo.bar
      </div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really up to your app to decide how it should look when it doesn't have the data it needs to render. Common approaches are

-show nothing

-show loading spinner

-show placeholder content that roughly matches how the content will look once loaded.

Showing nothing can work in a lot of cases, particularly if your load times are quick. A spinner is probably appropriate if the load time is typically slower. Placeholder content takes a bit more effort, but can provide a less jarring loading experience, since the structure of the page can be shown immediately and then the data just fills in when it is loaded.